# How to make search on all fields (title and tags as well as body)?

Tags: 7, search

The built in search engine in Drupal 7 doesn't search on the title or tags fields, just on the **body** of the node. I need to be able to search on all fields.

What is the best module to install for this if I'm running Drupal on Apache on Windows?

Answer (score 32):

One thing you can do to control which fields are included in your search index is to go to your specific content type's '**Manage Display**' page.

So go to Structure --> Content types --> Your content type --> Manage display.

On that screen, you'll see a collapsed section called 'Custom Display Settings'.  Just click on it to expand it.  You should see that you can check to enable the 'Search index' display to be customized (Usually only the teaser or summary is included for customization by default).  Check the 'Search index' box and save:

[image]

That will provide you with a brand new "Search index" tab on this screen.  Click on it and start customizing which fields you want to be included for this content type's search index:

[image]

Comment: thank you !! I couldnt find this anywhere on the drupal site

Comment: You're most welcome!

Comment: but the only thing is that the "Title" field is not one which is available on this page to put as visible .  what can we do to make the title be included in the search as well?

Comment: The title should be searched by default actually. And make sure you rebuild your search index after making changes like the above, so the new fields are picked up!

Comment: thanks , I dont understand why even when I rebuild mysearch engine and run cron and update,  my search doesnt find all of the items until the next day!

Comment: Diana, I'm not sure why that's happening. It could actually be a caching issue (not just on the Drupal end, but on the server end too, perhaps)? Maybe others can chime in here.

Comment: By the way, not regarding this answer of course, since it may not have solved your entire problem, but just in general on the StackExchange sites, I wanted to point out that you can accept or upvote answers that help you by using the check mark or arrows next to answers. I just notice you have never accepted an answer, and that may be because your issues were never fully resolved, which is totally fine, but if it's just an education thing, I wanted to explain that practice!

Comment: it wont let me vote up since I dont have a reputation of at least 15 . so please increase my reputation so I can vote for your answer !

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. Not sure why, but it didn't actually fix my problem. Nonetheless, seems like a step in the right direction.