# How to make summary of body searchable?

Tags: views, search, cron

I've already looked at [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69703/how-to-make-search-search-on-all-fields-title-and-tags-as-well-as-body) and tried to change the search index view so that when I ran a search, I could type in a word appearing in a summary it would appear in my search results. I also ran cron to get the site reindexed but still, nothing appears when I type in a word that only appears in a summary. 
How do I make the summaries in content searchable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not figure out to do this, but a workaround was to actually make a separate field called summary and remove the default body and add a new body field without a summary.